# Annoying Background-Position problem

Tags: qt

[image: This what it looks like]

this is my stylesheet:

```
QLineEdit#SearchBarEditBox {
    background: white;
    background-image: url(:/images/magnifyingGlass.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px 5px;
}
```

My Problem: "background-position" only receives "top/bottom/right/left" values. Any attempt to use a numerical absolute value results immediately in a "top center" justification for my image. Going crazy here....

Comment: BTW: The image by is tiny in size, and just fully encompasses the magnifying glass.

Comment: `background-position` does accept pixel values. Try `background-position: -2px 5px;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qt stylesheets don't implement full CSS, you can only use `center/top/left/bottom/right` for `background-position`.

See [background-position](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/stylesheet-reference.html#background-repeat-prop) and [alignment](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/stylesheet-reference.html#alignment) in the *Qt Stylesheet Reference*.

Comment: That sucks. So I guess I'd have to "pad" my own bitmap for me to be able to project it in an absolute position?

Comment: I don't see any other ways of doing it, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's an old question, I would like to answer for those who has the same issue still nowadays.

I solved it using the `background-origin` property:

> The widget's background rectangle, to use in conjunction with background-position and background-image. [...] If this property is not specified, the default is padding.

The complete stylesheet to solve the question issue is:

```
QLineEdit#SearchBarEditBox{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 10px; /* top - right - bottom - left */
    background-image: url(:/icons/search.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    background-origin: content; /* the left margin of background image will 'obey' the padding-left defined up above (10px) */
}
```

[image: Result]

Just for testing, try to change padding from '10px' to '30px' to see what happens.

**UPDATE** based on @Soyal7 comment:

Depending on the type of the component you're using, there's one more thing to do in order to prevent text overlaping:

**`QLineEdit`**: Use `ui->SearchBarEditBox->setTextMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);` to add a left text margin;

**`QPushButton`**: You can subclass `QPushButton` and reimplement `paintEvent()` method, or if you want a simpler workaround, just add some blank spaces before your text.

**`QLabel`**: Use `indent` property like this:

[image: Set left margin]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nice workaround, although if the button contains text, it's going to overlap. Not a big deal because you can add some spaces before the text.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer approaching these cases.